# How to show data from API in component table?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using Angular with Material-Angular and I want show data from Reqres API (https://reqres.in). So I built a table with pagination, but my pagination doesn't work.

I created service and model for data which I want keep, using HttpClient of course. In component class I created two variables for keep this data:
`users: User[]` and `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>(this.user)`.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../config/user.module';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users-list',
  templateUrl: './users-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users-list.component.sass']
})
export class UsersListComponent implements OnInit {
  users: User[];
  page: number;

  displayedColumns = ['Id', 'FirstName'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>(this.users);

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    this.showUsers();
  }

  showUsers() {
    this.page = 1;
    this.dataService.getUsers(this.page)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.users = res['data'];
      });
  }

}
```

And my template.html file:

```html
<section class="list">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="users" class="mat-elevation-z8 table">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <span class="table-header">No.</span>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">
        <span class="table-value">{{user.id}}</span>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="FirstName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <span class="table-header">Name</span>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">
        <span class="table-value">{{user.first_name}}</span>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[3]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</section>
```

So when I change `users` on `dataSource` in html file: `<table mat-table [dataSource]="HERE" class="mat-elevation-z8 table">`, I don't see any results in my table. 
I thought `dataSource` is well declared, type of `User` model and get data from `users` but doesn't work. If I change on `users` all display very well, but I need `dataSource` to pagination. The problem is time, when data don't exist in `users` in the time of calling or what?

Using: Angular-CLI 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind your dataSource directive to the object of type MatTableDataSource(not users) as it will help you with all sorting and pagination.

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8 table">
```

Then, you need to update the MatTableDataSource object where you have subscribed to the observable(returned by getUsers).

```
showUsers() {
this.page = 1;
this.dataService.getUsers(this.page)
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.datasource = new MatTableDataSource(res['data']);
  });
```

Other alternative is using the renderRows method. It can be helpful if you are calling the API multiple times, as it updates the rows for the new changes.

Here's the official stackbitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-render-rows?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts

Comment: Oh, it helped. Thanks, but what I should do with `dataSource` above constructor declaration?

Comment: Glad to help. Mat Table doesn't throw an error if dataSource is undefined, rather show an empty table. You can either leave the way it is, or just declare the dataSource with the type without initializing it. 
And please accept the answer if it solved the problem. :)